# making completed webform entries show in separate report/view

Tags: webforms

I have created a webform for tracking orders (customer, p/n, order date ship date etc)
I'm trying to figure out how to have entries with the ship date entered to not show in the view so people just see whats in process. It would be OK to have an archive or close link or simply have them dissapear when the ship date is entered but I would still need a report or view for closed orders only. Or, how can I simply mark entries as closed? I assume it would be easy to create a link to the closed records. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. thx